# Problems with deriving the Fourier transform of $|\vec{r}|^{n}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, multiple-integral

I would like to be able to derive the following Fourier transform identity: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{d^{D}p}{(2\pi)^{D}}\, |\vec{p}|^{\alpha}e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}} = \left(\frac{2}{r}\right)^{\alpha + D}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha +D}{2})}{(4\pi)^{D/2}\Gamma(-\frac{\alpha}{2})},$$ where $\Gamma(z)$ is the gamma fucntion.

I presume that this equation is symbolic in the sense that the integral on the left-hand side needs to be regulated in some way in order to get the finite result on the right-hand side. I'm really unsure how to proceed though. I tried expressing the integral in spherical polar coordinates, but that doesn't seem to help. I've also tried introducing a regulator of the form $e^{-\epsilon |\vec{p}|^{2}}$, where $\epsilon$ is small, but finite. Unfortunately this hasn't seemed to help either. I must be missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many dimensions are we talking here? I've done this before and found it helpful to break this into D >= 3 vs D < 3.

Comment: @KitterCatter    I would like to show it in general, but at the end of the day I need it for D = 3.

Comment: When you have n-dimensional radial symmetry, the Fourier Transform has a special form.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3015829/441161 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3029986/441161 for some hints.

Comment: @AndyWalls     Thanks for the hints. I presume that the radial Fourier transform identity that you give in your linked answer works in reverse too (i.e. if I switch the roles of s and r)?

Comment: The radially symmetric versions of the 2-D and 3-D Fourier Transforms, as presented by Bracewell, are their own inverse transforms.  I.e. $r$, the radial variable in the original domain, is swapped with $q$, the radial variable in the transform domain, to obtain the inverse transform.  (I'm not sure what you mean by swapping the roles of $r$ and $s$.)

Comment: @AndyWalls     I meant the is the inverse Fourier transform of the same form. So it holds in 2-D and 3-D, does it hold in n-dimensions? i.e. is it its own inverse in n-dimensions?

Comment: Intuitively, I believe the answer is "yes", but I do not have a proof or a statement by an author stating this.  You can probably subit it as a question to http://math.stackexchange.com . :)

Comment: @AndyWalls     Ok. Thanks, I'll consider doing that.

Comment: @KitterCatter  Do you have any details on how you went about it?

Comment: @Will I think it's something similar to what Andy gave out. Essentially I exploited the azimuthal angle choice to integrate over the cosine between $p$ and $r$. The rest of the angular integrals were trivial. You are then just doing a couple of simple azimuth/power integrals.

Comment: @Will I looked over my notes though and I was looking only at something that was exponential and had an inverse power ($e^{-\epsilon p}/p$)

Comment: @KitterCatter  Thank you for looking into it.